# Is the vector in the space of 3 other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a set of 3 vectors
   $$ IE = {[1, 1, -3]; [2, -1, 3]; [-6, 3, -9]}$$

I want to know if the vector [1, 4, -12] , belongs (or is in the span?) to my previous set.

So here's what I did.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & -6 & [c1]\\
        1 & -1 & 3 & [c2]\\
        -3 & 3 & -9 & [c3]\\
        \end{matrix}
=  \begin{matrix}
        1 \\
        4 \\
        -12 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Now I start Gauss

L2-L1

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & -6 \\
        0 & -3 & 9 \\
        -3 & 3 & -9 \\
        \end{matrix}
=       \begin{matrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
        -12 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

L3+3L1

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & -6 \\
        0 & -3 & 9 \\
        0 & 9 & -27 \\
        \end{matrix}
=       \begin{matrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
        -9 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

L2 / 3

and then L3-9L2

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & -6 \\
        0 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
=       \begin{matrix}
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

My Answer :

1. The variable C3 (3rd column) has no pivot. which means it is a free variable.
2. There is no contradiction , so the vector $$ [1, 4, -12] $$ is in the space of my                                       Set.

I have 2 questions :

1. **does the fact that I have a free variable change anything ?**
2. A contradiction happens when I have a line full of zeros that equals a non zero value, right ?

Like

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
=       \begin{matrix}
        2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

**Is there any other way to have a contradiction ?**

Sorry if the title isn't clear, I have trouble traducing the question..

Thanks

Comment: Note that you also multiplied L2 by -1 at some point at the end to reach your conclusion - what you have written is correct, I'm just pointing out that you did one more row-reduction step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

1. The fact that you have a free variable means many things. For instance, it means that your original set of three vectors were linearly dependent (one equals a linear combination of the other two). Therefore there *are* vectors which are outside the span of these three vectors.

   We could also continue row reduction to find out just what values of $c_1,c_2,c_3$ give the linear combination we are interested in:

   $$
   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
   1 & 2 & -6 &1 \\
   0 & 1 & -3 &-1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 &0\end{array} \right] \sim
   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
   1 & 0 & 0 &3 \\
   0 & 1 & -3 &-1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 &0\end{array} \right]$$

   So $c_1=3$, and $c_2=3c_3 - 1$. Let's see if this works in general:
   $$
   3\left[ \begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   -3\end{array} \right] +
   (3c_3-1)\left[ \begin{array}{c}
   2 \\
   -1 \\
   3\end{array} \right]+
   c_3\left[ \begin{array}{c}
   -6 \\
   3 \\
   -9\end{array} \right]  =
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
   3+2(3c_3-1)-6c_3 \\
   3-(3c_3-1)+3c_3 \\
   -9+3(3c_3-1)-9c_3\end{array} \right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   4 \\
   -12\end{array} \right]  $$
   So this means you can actually find *infinitely many* linear combinations by taking different values for $c_3$.
2. If you do row reduction, that is essentially the only way to have a contradiction. The reason it is a contradiction is because if you remember that the matrix is "shorthand" for a system of linear equations, the linear equation corresponding to a row of zeros on the left and a number like 2 on the right is of the form$$0c_1 + 0c_2 + 0c_3 = 2 \implies 0 = 2$$
   which is why it is a contradiction. Any other time, if you reduce to row echelon form and you don't have a row of zeros on the left corresponding to a nonzero number in the augmented column, you essentially are using "back-substitution" to solve the system of equations.